# Finding a length of a set?

Tags: formal-languages

Let $\Sigma=\{a,b,c\}$ and let $\Sigma^*$ be the set of all words $w$ using letters from $\Sigma$.

Define $$L(w)=\text{length}(w)$$ for all $w\in\Sigma^*$.

How to calculate the L(w) for the words w1=ababac and w2=λ?

(Is there any link where i can learn these calculations in details)

Answer (score 1):

The length of the word `abc` is 3 because it contains 3 letters.

The length of the word `aaabbb` is 6 because it contains 6 letters.

Does that help?

Comment: if we calculate aaabbb for Σ={a,b,c}, is that counted as length = 2 or length = 6??

Comment: Didn't I just say it is 6?

Comment: Ok thank you. 
btw: if we want to find all the words w such that L(w)=2, how i can achieve this??

Comment: @hrskrs: How many ways are there to put two letters next to each other?

Comment: @HenningMakholm ok i know it but i was just being sure about that. Thank you.